# Can I retrieve a Slack app's Signing Secret via an api?

Tags: slack, slack-api

I'm developing a Slack app and I want to enable automated testing on feature-branches. I want to create a new Slack app for each branch and delete the app when the branch is merged.

I can create a new app easily using a manifest file and the https://api.slack.com/methods/apps.manifest.create api.
My Slackbot application code (Python + Bolt) uses the app signing secret to validate messages it receives are sent from Slack, so after creating the app I need to retrieve the automatically-generated Signing Secret from Slack, which my app would read from something like AWS Secrets Manager.

I don't want to manually copy-paste the Signing Secret from the Slack App configuration. I can't see anything in the Slack API (from https://api.slack.com/methods) which lets you retrieve this value. Is there any way to automate retrieving this secret?

I've searched Google and looked through the methods on the slack api at https://api.slack.com/methods but I can't see any way to retrieve this Signing Secret programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to retrieve the signing secret through an API and never will be, since it would be an inherent security risk.

A Signing Secret is a sensible piece of information like a password, something you'd never want to be accessible through an API.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you clarify how this would be an inherent security risk? I can access this secret using my credentials in a browser, which must be retrieving the secret over HTTPS anyway.

Comment: @Andrew it is about minimizing the risk of leaking the signing secret. Having a single secure environment that you control (like the admin page) ensures that the secret cannot be accessed by an unauthorized party. Someone would need access to your account and at this point you as the user / developer are at fault. It also reduces the work, testing and auditing that needs to be done from Slack's side. Your use case is also pretty niché, meaning the security factors far outweigh the "inconvenience" you might experience.

Comment: We'll agree to disagree about whether CI/CD automation is niche and whether this is secure. Thank you for your answer though, it seems there is no api method to retrieve this data.